# Excluding a specific node from being assigned for a Kubernetes job

Tags: kubernetes

I have a specific node I know by hostname (as seen in `kubectl describe pods`). I suspect a hardware incompatibility and would like to exclude that node from my job.

I've tried to use `podAntiAffinity` without success (my job is still assigned to `my.hostname.net`). What is the correct way to accomplish this?

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: my-job-name
spec:
  backoffLimit: 0
  template:
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
                operator: NotIn
                values:
                - my.hostname.net
            topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
      containers:
        <<the rest omitted>>
```

Comment: `podAntiAffinity` forbids placing pods together on that node. It looks like there is no node anti-affinity available at all. You technically could add taint to the node, but then you would have to add toleration to all other payloads.

Comment: As a non-admin can taints be added at the namespace level? I am under the assumption that taints are globally added to the cluster by an administrator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah, I figured it out thanks to @zerkms's comment. Using `nodeAffinity` with the `NotIn` operator excludes nodes by hostname as desired:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: my-job-name
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
                operator: NotIn
                values:
                - my.hostname.net
                - another.hostname.net
      containers:
        <<omitted>>
```

Comment: Right, I had a feeling that there should be a negation operator, but I did not bother to check and only relied on memory. Sorry for that :-)